# Woocommerce Switch User Role based on customer total purchases amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

I'm using the code from [here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-switch-user-role-if-customer-spent-more-than/).

It changes the user's role after reaching the purchase amounts.
My attempts to expand it and check some conditions:

1. The amount of the period during which purchases must be verified is 2 years. if over a period of 2 years the amount of purchases is not equal to 5000, then the status must be recalculated again and a role must be assigned to him in accordance with his order amount.
   Here are the amounts I plan to use:

`$threshold_amount_to_silver = 4999.99;`

`$threshold_amount_to_gold = 9999.99;`

`$threshold_amount_to_platinum = 14999.99;`

2. The amount of purchases should include only orders that have a `completed` status, and if orders were canceled or their status is somehow different from the completed status, then the amount should be reduced and the order status recalculated again. If a return was made, the purchase amount must be reduced by the refund amount.
3. Recalculation occurs only among the roles: `subscriber`, `customer`, `karta-silver`, `karta-gold`, `karta-platinum`.

I tried to add my own changes to the code using the silver condition as an example.
But it does not work and the roles are not recalculated.
Any help please.

```
function bbloomer_maybe_trigger_switch_user_role( $order_id ) {
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
   $order_status = $order->get_status();
   $switch_already_done = $order->get_meta( '_bb_role_switched' );

   $roles_to_check = array( 'subscriber', 'customer', 'karta-platinum', 'karta-gold', 'karta-silver' );
   if ( ! $switch_already_done && $order->has_status( wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ) ) {
      foreach ( $roles_to_check as $role ) {
         if ( wc_user_has_role( $user_id, $role ) ) {
            bbloomer_customer_maybe_upgrade_to_silver( $user_id );
            $order->update_meta_data( '_bb_role_switched', 'true' );
            $order->save();
            break; 
         }
      }
   }
}

function bbloomer_customer_maybe_upgrade_to_silver( $user_id ) {
   $threshold_amount_to_silver = 4999.99; 
   $threshold_date  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years')); 
   $total_spent = wc_get_customer_total_spent( $user_id, $threshold_date ); 
   if ( $total_spent > $threshold_amount_to_silver ) {
      $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
      $user->add_role( 'karta-silver' );
      $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
      $user->remove_role( 'customer' );
      $user->remove_role( 'karta-gold' );
      $user->remove_role( 'karta-platinum' );
   }
}
```